# Unit Testing for GUI

Tags: java, jsp, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I just recently began looking into unit testing and would like to implement it on my webpage (using JPA, JSP, and MySQL). 
I can understand how I can use JUnit for testing simple things like retrieving user information from the database, but cannot understand how to automate test something like login failing when the username field is blank.

Comment: And why do you need **unit** testing? I mean you have presentation layer (JSP), service layer, persistence layer (JPA+MySQL), all these are participating in login process. You can validate data by javascript at JSP, or at service, or even by database constraints. Which unit from these do you want to test?

Comment: Hmm I guess what I really want is to perform automated testing quickly in one place like with Java's JUnit rather than having to manually go through each webpage to check if anything got broken.

Comment: If you are testing all the layers (presentation, service, persistence), not just how your `html`+`js` behave then it is integration test or even end-to-end, and you need to use corresponding tools, and JUnit is not among them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Unit test then you should identify which unit your are wanting to test. Let's say you have a SecurityService with a login method that takes a username and password and returns a boolean indicating whether the user logged in or not. Then you could just pass null in for the user to test that it returns false.

If you have some javascript that doesn't allow the user to click submit when the username is blank, then you will have a write some kind of javascript unit test for that part since it is a different unit.

The main thing when trying to write a testable web application with java that I have found is making sure that you have very little logic in your presentation layer code. Make sure that when a user clicks a button that you are immediately sending something to a "Service" of some kind to do the work. That way you can test the service in isolation of the presentation layer.

Here's a code example of a test for the SecurityService I mentioned.

```
public class SecurityService
{
    public boolean login(String username, String password)
    {
        //Put your logic here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the junit test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SecurityServiceTest
{
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        securityService = new SecurityService();
        //Mock any database access you need here, like DAOs.
        //example: securityService.setUserDAO(myMockUserDAO);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginWithNull_False()
    {
        assertFalse(securityService.login(null, "123"));
    }
}
```